# Cannot connect via ssh to a device (only on Widonws10, on Linux and MacOs it works fine)

Tags: ssh, windows-10, window

As described in the title:
I cannot connect via ssh to a device (only with Widonws10,  on Linux and MacOs it works fine).
The ip address of the device is the following: 192.168.1.61

Trying to exedcute :

```
ssh root@192.168.1.61
```

On Windows 10 returns

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.61 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Please note the same command works fine on Linux and MacOs.

(Ping fails as well , only on Windows)

I tried to disable the Firewall same result, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Surely the ssh daemon is set on another port.

You need to run command **netstat -an** on the server to know which port is using.
If you don't have fisic access on the server try **telnet host port (or telnet host: port on Unix systems)** to see if there is something on listening.